# Facebook Login in Private Mode. How is this possible?

Tags: facebook, cookies, authentication

I just realised that Facebook allows me to log in even in private mode (i.e. with cookies disabled). This works in both Firefox and Safari.

Even if I close the window and then open another Private window, I am still logged in.

Does anybody know how this works?? Is it black magic?

I mean, I sort of knew that even in Private Mode, companies could still track me, but I would not have thought that this would be so reliable that they'd allow something security-relevant, such as a login..

Thanks!

Comment: “Private mode” does not mean that cookies are disabled per se.

Comment: Firefox specifically states that cookies are disabled in Private windows.

Comment: Really, where? Not storing cookies for longer than the browser session, and not accepting cookies at all, are still two different things.

Comment: Just when you open a private window, FF says:

"Private Browsing with Tracking Protection

When you browse **in a Private Window, Firefox does not save**:

visited pages
**cookies**
searches
temporary files"

Comment: Yes, it does not store them, so that they could be seen in the next browsing session (after you close and reopen the browser.) But that of course does not mean it completely disallows the use of all cookies during your session.